# findbugs cannot detect NumberFormatException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, findbugs

I use [findbugs intellij plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3847?pr=idea) and it cannot detect the potential NumberFormatException in following code:

```
// potentially throw uncatched NumberFormatException exception and crash the program
public void foo() {
    int s = Integer.parseInt("ddd");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

There is one rule called [method might drop exception](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#DE_MIGHT_DROP)
and therefore I assume it should be able to find out that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

DE_MIGHT_DROP refers to exceptions being "swallowed", i.e. not reported properly even though they are thrown. Your method would throw the exception, so DE_MIGHT_DROP is satisfied.

I don't think there is a detector for what you seek, because the detector cannot know whether you want the exception caught or not.

Comment: A rule to detect wherever a runtime exception is not handled would not be practical. On the other hand, if NFE was an Exception (not RuntimeException) then you'd have a compiler error ;)

Comment: @vikingsteve why it is not practical? shouldn't wherever a runtime exception thrown be handled, especially in production?

Comment: @qqibrow That's the whole problem with runtime exceptions. They should be handled - but the question is: "where" ? In "this" method or "somewhere further up". That's a design design and outside of the scope of code analysis tools.

Comment: @vikingsteve you are right. I understand this is sort of a design problem. My starting point is to find out all kinds of RuntimeException could be thrown from my function. I wish I can get that from either a static analysis tool or the IDE. Checking all lines in the function to sum up the list of all potential RuntimeException, I think such a tool is possible. what do u think?

Comment: Well, in Java there is a general distinction between *checked* exceptions, which by definition should be handled, and *runtime* exceptions, which by definition do not need to be handled (at least not right away). So a detector which makes you treat runtime exceptions like checked exceptions would go against a fundamental principle of Java.

Answer (score 0):

FindBugs detects bugs and bug patterns.  The problem is that this for sure is a bug but it is unclear what bug pattern this fits and how often this bug pattern occurs in the wild.  Without simply ripping up the whole example here are some ranked proposed patterns that could be added:

1. UM: Method calls parse on constant value (UM_UNNECESSARY_PARSE)
2. Dm: Hardcoded constant used with parseXXX (DMI_CONSTANT_PARSE)
3. DM: Base 10 parseXXX must be numeric or call two argument parseXXX.

Comment: hmm... those are too specific. what I want is a reminder or warning that I didn't write an error handler to handler the RuntimeException, NumberFormatException. Could `findbugs` do that? if not, is there any tool can do that?